# How to define fixed parts of interface members

Tags: .net, vb.net, interface

This is my interface :

```
Public Interface IProductComputer 
   Sub CalculatePrice
   Sub CalculateTax
   Sub Calculate
End Interface
```

And here are my classes :

```
Public Class Product1 
       Implements IProductComputer
     ........
End Class

Public Class Product2
       Implements IProductComputer
    ......
End Class
```

Problem :

My interface can be used in an unlimited number of classes and of course it should be implemented in all of them separately. But what if there are some common parts in an method?. For example there may be a common formula in CalculateTax method and it does not seem very pleasant to include this formula in all implementations (Instead implementing this formula in interface and implementing uncommon parts in classes which implements interface).

I've seen some .Net predefined interfaces which have some fixed parts like IDisposable (It has some kind of primary implementation when you implement it). Is there any approach to create an interface like them?

(above code is written in Vb.Net but I know C# syntaxes too)
Let me explain more if I'm not clear enough.

Comment: Can you use an abstract base class?

Comment: If you want to use common code in your classes I think you have to use a Base class and let your Product classes inherit from that. You can then decide whether the product classes are allowed to override the base class method or not

Comment: Inheritance might help: the base class would define a common `CalculateTax` method, then those classes which do it differently can override it.  For things which vary a lot, define is as `MustOVerride Calculate` in the base so that the child classes have to implement it as with an interface.

Comment: Does `VB.NET` have extensions methods? It seems that with `C#` you can create a common method to operate on `IProductComputer` regardless of the concrete type.

Comment: @nickfinity. Yes but what if I already have used a base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is no: Interfaces cannot contain code, there is simply an accepted pattern for IDisposable which is implemented many times over.

However, there are a couple of ways around this

- You can implement and `abstract` class instead of an interface. You lose some of the implementation ability, since it's now a class and thus implementations cannot inherit from a different class. However, this is considered the primary difference between interfaces and abstract classes - code
- It IS possible to write [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) which target interfaces, allowing you use common code for certain common operations. This, however, becomes very limited since extension methods will only be able to access interface memebers, and are static and thus cannot be overidden in any way. While you could rewrite a method with the same name in a derived class, any compilation which targets the extension method will continue to target that extension method regardless.

Comment: So final answer is : There are no useful approach to this

Answer (score 2):

By definition, an interface cannot have any methods/properties implemented, they can only be defined. You have two options to work around this:

1. Change your implementation from an interface to an abstract class (I believe that is MustInherit in VB.net). Abstract classes can have some members implemented, while other members are only defined.
2. Leave it as an interface, and if you have methods that you already have an implementation for, you can implement them as extension methods for your interface.

Neither of these solutions may be perfect for you, but hopefully one will be well-suited enough to your needs.